# Does Google's own bot contribute to my Google Maps API fees?

Tags: google, googlebot, google-maps, google-api

Does Googlebot, when crawling pages which display maps using the Javascript API, cause a billable API usage on each page request?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. At the end of August, a 20-fold increase in the Googlebot crawl rate pushed my site into the paying band for the Maps API. Three days of being monstered cost me €174.

Fish in a barrel?

Answer (score 0):

An investigation into the Google Robots.txt file...

```
https://www.google.com/robots.txt
Allow: /maps?*output=classic*
Allow: /maps?*file=
Allow: /maps/api/js?
Allow: /maps/d/
```

Has Google's own crawler pushed up the maps views on your website?  It looks like it might have.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answers the question? Your answer as written is not very clear to me.

Comment: Sure.  It appears that Google's Robots.txt file (the file that tells Google what to crawl and what not to crawl on its own domain) may allow the crawling of the /maps.  When you add Google Maps to your website, you're basically embedding code from their domain, so crawl rates are controlled by them.